# How to get predicted values on Sigmoid Growth model in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I am trying to forecast future revenue by using Sigmoid growth model in R. The model is like this:

```
Y = a/( 1+ce^(-bX) ) + noise
```

my code:

```
x <- seq(-5,5,length=n)
y <- 1/(1+exp(-x))
plot(y~x, type='l', lwd=3)
title(main='Sigmoid Growth')
```

I could draw the plot, but I don't know how to get the future values. Suppose I want to predict the next 6 years revenue values.

Answer (score 1):

Make `y` a function, and plot that (`plot` has special support for functions):

```
y <- function(x) 1/(1+exp(-x))
plot(y,-5,11,type="l",lwd=3)
```

Comment: But this just plot the function smoothly, when I typed "y", it shows that >function(x) 1/(1+exp(-x))  , not the predicted values.

Comment: To get the values, `y(6:11)`